# Add canonical link tag to head using PHP

Tags: php, html, joomla

Google won't recognize the Canonical link tag unless its in the Head, I wont bore you with the details but I can only edit the article page on a Joomla site. I have custom code anywhere installed so I can insert PHP into the article.

Is there a piece of PHP I can add that will add a canonical link tag in my `<head>`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think JDocumentHTML is what you need.
See this [documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/JDocumentHTML/addCustomTag).

Comment: thanks , this is what I needed, not sure why i was down voted for the question but ok